# What is the html code to automatically request desktop site for android browser?

Tags: android, html, request, desktop

Please help me
I decided to develop an android application which navigate to web.whatsapp.com
so i created a local html site to convert it to apk.
But when the app opened in mobile, the site redirected to whatsapp.com
how to prevent it?

Comment: Hello, you should provide more detail. Please read this article. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Try this settings with webView.**

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Now load website.